# JS- how to change option color base on if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the option color base on an if statment. This is my form:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var lia = document.createElement("h5");
  var lib = document.createElement("p");

  var item = document.getElementById('task').value;
  var pro = document.getElementById('priority').value;

  var item_list = document.createTextNode(item);
  var item_pro = document.createTextNode(pro);

  lia.appendChild(item_list);
  lib.appendChild(item_pro);

  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(lia);
  document.getElementById("priorit").appendChild(lib);

  if (pro == 'Urgent') {
    $("p").css('color', 'red');
  }
  if (pro == 'Critical') {
    $("p").css('color', 'orange');
  }
  if (pro == 'Normal') {
    $("p").css('color', 'green');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="task" type="text" />
<select id="priority">
  <option id="Urgent">Urgent</option>
  <option id="Critical">Critical</option>
  <option id="Normal">Normal</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<h3>List Result</h3>
<table>
  <th id="result"></th>
  <th id="priorit"></th>
<table>
```

This if statement its what i want to do. but for now, any time im adding to the list another item with other option, all the colors are change to the last one.
you can see my problem here:

https://jsbin.com/selenifepa/edit?html,js,output

what should i do?

Comment: your CSS selector used is pointing to all the paragraph elements inside your DOM, which is causing all to changed its color.

Comment: `$("p")` means "all `<p>` elements on the page".

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hefuqopibe/1/edit?html,js,output
 here is the Updated Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:last-child` css selector.

See this code

```js
function myFunction() {

var lia = document.createElement("h5");
var lib = document.createElement("p");

var item = document.getElementById('task').value;
var pro = document.getElementById('priority').value;

var item_list = document.createTextNode(item);
var item_pro = document.createTextNode(pro);

lia.appendChild(item_list);
lib.appendChild(item_pro);

document.getElementById("result").appendChild(lia);
document.getElementById("priorit").appendChild(lib);


if(pro=='Urgent'){
   $("p:last-child").css('color','red');
 }
 if(pro=='Critical'){
   $("p:last-child").css('color','orange');
 }
 if(pro=='Normal'){
   $("p:last-child").css('color','green');
 }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="task" type="text"/>
<select id="priority">
<option id="Urgent">Urgent</option>
<option id="Critical">Critical</option>
<option id="Normal">Normal</option>
 </select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<h3>List Result</h3>
<table>
<th id="result"></th>
<th id="priorit"></th>
<table>
```

Comment: if it possible i want to ask u another question.. how can i sort the list order by priority? any new Urgent task will show first, after that Critical, after normal and etc. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting all paragraph elements, you can select added element like this:

```
if(pro=='Urgent'){
   $(lib).css('color','red');
 }
 if(pro=='Critical'){
   $(lib).css('color','orange');
 }
 if(pro=='Normal'){
   $(lib).css('color','green');
 }
```

Replace your if with this one and this is it...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `$('p')` selector matches all existing `p` elements in the DOM, not just the one you added. You can fix that by using `$(lib)` to affect only the newly added `p` tag.

```
$(lib).css('color', 'green');
```

However, I would also suggest you look in to using unobtrusive event handlers as `on*` event attributes are considered outdated. As you're already using jQuery, here's how to do that:

```js
$('#add').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pro = $('#priority').val();
  var $lia = $("<h5 />").text($('#task').val()).appendTo('#result');
  var $lib = $("<p />").text(pro).appendTo('#priorit');

  if (pro == 'Urgent') {
    $lib.css('color', 'red');
  }
  if (pro == 'Critical') {
    $lib.css('color', 'orange');
  }
  if (pro == 'Normal') {
    $lib.css('color', 'green');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="task" type="text" />
<select id="priority">
  <option id="Urgent">Urgent</option>
  <option id="Critical">Critical</option>
  <option id="Normal">Normal</option>
</select>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<h3>List Result</h3>
<table>
  <th id="result"></th>
  <th id="priorit"></th>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are selecting all the `p` tags with `$('p')`. Also, you have mixed jQuery with vanilla JS. I'll assume you want to use jQuery to simplify your code. Here it goes.

```js
function add() {
  // select the elements and assign to a var, that way we don't have to be selecting the elements over and over, which is 'slow' (research "Why traversing the DOM is slow")
  var results = $('#results'),
  task = $('#task'),
  priority = $('#priority'),
  
  // create the new div element with it's content
  newResult = $('<div>'+task.val()+' '+priority.val()+'</div>');

  // Decide what color to apply
  if(priority.val() == 'Urgent'){
    newResult.css('color','red');
  }
  
  if(priority.val() == 'Critical'){
    newResult.css('color','orange');
  }
  
  if(priority.val() == 'Normal'){
    newResult.css('color','green');
  }
  
  // append the new div to the list of results
  results.append(newResult);
  
  // clear the input and focus the cursor for the next value to be added
  task.val('').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="task" type="text"/>
<select id="priority">
<option id="Urgent">Urgent</option>
<option id="Critical">Critical</option>
<option id="Normal">Normal</option>
 </select>

<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<h3>List Result</h3>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here This should do the trick

```
function myFunction() {

    var lia = document.createElement("h5");
    var lib = document.createElement("p");


  var item = document.getElementById('task').value;
  var pro = document.getElementById('priority').value;


  var item_list = document.createTextNode(item);
  var item_pro = document.createTextNode(pro);

  lia.appendChild(item_list);
  lib.appendChild(item_pro);
  if(pro=='Urgent'){
    lia.style.color='red';
     lib.style.color='red';  
}else{
  lia.style.color='orange';
     lib.style.color='orange';
}

    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(lia);
  document.getElementById("priorit").appendChild(lib);



document.getElementById('task').value = '';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue was that you're selectin all the `p` elements by `$("p")`. You need to just select the currently added element i.e. `lib`. But `lib` is a javascript variable, so wrap it in jQuery to convert it into a jQuery object and then apply jQuery `css`.

e.g. `$(lib).css('color', 'red');`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var lia = document.createElement("h5");
  var lib = document.createElement("p");

  var item = document.getElementById('task').value;
  var pro = document.getElementById('priority').value;

  var item_list = document.createTextNode(item);
  var item_pro = document.createTextNode(pro);

  lia.appendChild(item_list);
  lib.appendChild(item_pro);

  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(lia);
  document.getElementById("priorit").appendChild(lib);

  if (pro == 'Urgent') {
    $(lib).css('color', 'red');
  }
  if (pro == 'Critical') {
    $(lib).css('color', 'orange');
  }
  if (pro == 'Normal') {
    $(lib).css('color', 'green');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="task" type="text" />
<select id="priority">
  <option id="Urgent">Urgent</option>
  <option id="Critical">Critical</option>
  <option id="Normal">Normal</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<h3>List Result</h3>
<table>
  <th id="result"></th>
  <th id="priorit"></th>
  <table>
```